# MSI installer tool

Tags: windows-installer, gpo

I'm relatively new to MSI deployment and things like that. So pardon me if my questions seem odd.

So I have an MSI I want to GPO out. Problem with this MSI is the package itself requires user interaction if you install it manually. It's not the way I designed it, just the way it came. How would I be able to MSI this up so when it gets deployed out, Windows knows what to do to install it?

I know of Orca and tried this and it created an MST file, but I really did not see the MST file play out that well. Even when it was used in the GPO deployment in the advanced options.

Does anyone know of a better method of programming MSI packages when they are GPO'd out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to deal with this is to design the MSI so that it can be silently installed. This just means that the UI sets public properties to values, then these properties are used in the execute sequence. A silent install therefore just requires setting the property values on the msiexec command line.

Comment: Okay, so do you have an example of a program I can do this with? We're going to be receiving custom MSI packages and sending them out via GPO would save a lot of time.

Comment: It's nothing to do with a program. You design the MSI (using WiX or whatever it is you have) so that the MSI can be installed silently passing (on the command line) all the property values that would otherwise enter in the UI. It's a design pattern, not a program.